# Refresh img at some interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have following div inside my jsp file

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <img alt="" src="http://localhost:8080/chartDemo/servlet/ChartDemoServlet">
</div>
```

I want to automatically refresh the image at some interval.

I have tried with `<meta http-equiv="Refresh">` it works perfect but refreshes the whole page.

How do I refresh only the image?

Comment: I think you want to reload the image. You can't "refresh a div".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="myDiv" onload="JavaScript:timedRefresh(5000);">
        <img alt=""
            src="http://localhost:8080/chartDemo/servlet/ChartDemoServlet">
    </div>
```

put it in javascript

```
function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
    setTimeout("location.reload(true);",timeoutPeriod);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> I want to automatically refresh that div at some interval.

With what content? Or does the `img` change every time?

If so:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $("#myDiv").html('<img alt="" src="http://localhost:8080/chartDemo/servlet/ChartDemoServlet">');
}, 1000);
```

...should do it, once a second (1000ms = 1 second), provided the cache headers on the data returned by the `img`'s `src` URL are correct (otherwise, the browser may cache the earlier version). What that does is completely tear down the contents of the `div`, and then assign the given markup to it, which should recreate the `img` element and cause a re-fetch (again, provided the headers are right).

Answer (score 3):

```
setInterval(function() {
  // use to prevent browser cache
  var d = new Date();
  $("#myDiv img").attr("src", "http://localhost:8080/chartDemo/servlet/ChartDemoServlet?"+d.getTime());
}, 3000); // every 3 seconds.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use window.setInterval timer. In that function you give change the img src.
soemthing like this

```
//timer function
window.setInterval(refreshImage,1000);

function refreshImage()
{
     $('#urdiveid img').attr('src')='new location';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with JavaScript Timeout Function

```
var t=setTimeout("functiontoCall()", 3000)
```

You can write your own in `FunctiontoCall()` to load content in `myDiv`. It can be ajax call or simple Dom Manipulation